# What are all the fields in a Python ntplib response, and how are they used?

Tags: python, ntp

I'd like to make a measurement of the difference between a local clock, and 
a remote processor running an NTP server.

I can get the tx_time of the response, as shown below, but a better estimate would include some estimate of the network delays.  There are other fields in the NTP response message which should be used, as well.

```
import ntplib
from time import ctime,time

addr_remote = '128.128.204.207'

c = ntplib.NTPClient()
remote = c.request(addr_remote)
local = time()
print("REMOTE: " + ctime(remote.tx_time) + "   <reference clock>   ") 
print("LOCAL:  " + ctime(local)        + "   delta: " + str(local - remote.tx_time ))
```

If I look at "remote":

```
for attr in dir(remote):
    print("remote.%s = %r" % (attr, getattr(remote, attr)))
```

I see:

```
remote.delay = 0.0
remote.dest_time = 1531863145.9309998
remote.dest_timestamp = 3740851945.9309998
remote.from_data = <bound method NTPPacket.from_data of <ntplib.NTPStats object at 0x000000000265B2E8>>
remote.leap = 0
remote.mode = 4
remote.offset = -1.8789582252502441
remote.orig_time = 1531863145.9309998
remote.orig_timestamp = 3740851945.9309998
remote.poll = 0
remote.precision = -7
remote.recv_time = 1531863144.0520415
remote.recv_timestamp = 3740851944.0520415
remote.ref_id = 0
remote.ref_time = 0.0
remote.ref_timestamp = 2208988800.0
remote.root_delay = 0.0
remote.root_dispersion = 0.0
remote.stratum = 9
remote.to_data = <bound method NTPPacket.to_data of <ntplib.NTPStats object at 0x000000000265B2E8>>
remote.tx_time = 1531863144.0520415
remote.tx_timestamp = 3740851944.0520415
```

So, how do I use these:

- **dest_time**
- **orig_time**
- **recv_time**
- **tx_time**

to remove the network delays, and get a better estimate of the clock difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The NTP client sends a packet with its local time `orig_time`, which the NTP server receives at the server time `recv_time`. The server then replies at server time `tx_time` and the client receives that reply at local time `dest_time`.

The round trip `delay` is calculated as `recv_time - orig_time + dest_time - tx_time`, and the offset between the clocks is `offset = (recv_time - orig_time + tx_time - dest_time) / 2`.

Assuming the two NTP packets take consistent paths, the correct adjusted time is simply `dest_time + offset`, which is equivalent to `tx_time + delay/2`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer while trying to syncing my client computer to NTP time and checking that it actually synced. Based on @Vic, this means that the client clock (compared to the server NTP clock) is always off by:

```
dest_time + offset = tx_time + delay/2
dest_time - tx_time = delay/2 - offset
```

i.e.

```
correction = delay/2 - offset
```

As @Vic said, packets may take different routes going to and coming from, but in average `correction` should give you your clock offset (I think). Even by syncing with `time.nist.gov` with `os.system('w32tm /resync/nowait')`, my computer is always off by 40ms, somehow. Comments welcome!

This is my code.

```
import ntplib
from datetime import datetime, timezone
def get_ntp_time():
    ntp_pool = ['pool.ntp.org', 'time.nist.gov']
    def call_ntp(serverAddress):
        call = ntplib.NTPClient()
        return call.request(server, version=3)
    for server in ntp_pool:
        response = call_ntp(server)
        print(f"server: {server}")
        print(f"request packet sent (as LOCAL client time, orig_time): {datetime.fromtimestamp(response.orig_time, timezone.utc)}")
        print(f"request packet received (as NTP server time, recv_time): {datetime.fromtimestamp(response.recv_time, timezone.utc)}")
        print(f"response packet sent (as NTP server time, tx_time): {datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time, timezone.utc)}")
        print(f"response packet received (as LOCAL client time, dest_time): {datetime.fromtimestamp(response.dest_time, timezone.utc)}")
        print(f'round trip duration: {response.delay} s')
        print(f'* adjusted time, tx_time + delay/2: {datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time + response.delay/2, timezone.utc)}')
        print(f'* adjusted time, dest_time + offset: {datetime.fromtimestamp(response.dest_time + response.offset, timezone.utc)}')
        print(f'correction to client: {response.delay/2 - response.offset} s\n')
        # for attr in dir(response):
            # if not attr .startswith('_'):
                # print("response.%s = %r" % (attr, getattr(response, attr)))
        print('-')
get_ntp_time()
```

Response:

```
server: pool.ntp.org
request packet sent (as LOCAL client time, orig_time): 2021-04-23 16:14:46.544797+00:00
request packet received (as NTP server time, recv_time): 2021-04-23 16:14:46.535852+00:00
response packet sent (as NTP server time, tx_time): 2021-04-23 16:14:46.535862+00:00
response packet received (as LOCAL client time, dest_time): 2021-04-23 16:14:46.579710+00:00
round trip duration: 0.03490257263183594 s
* adjusted time, tx_time + delay/2: 2021-04-23 16:14:46.553314+00:00
* adjusted time, dest_time + offset: 2021-04-23 16:14:46.553314+00:00
correction to client: 0.04384756088256836 s

-
server: time.nist.gov
request packet sent (as LOCAL client time, orig_time): 2021-04-23 16:14:46.642192+00:00
request packet received (as NTP server time, recv_time): 2021-04-23 16:14:46.641157+00:00
response packet sent (as NTP server time, tx_time): 2021-04-23 16:14:46.641158+00:00
response packet received (as LOCAL client time, dest_time): 2021-04-23 16:14:46.689054+00:00
round trip duration: 0.04686117172241211 s
* adjusted time, tx_time + delay/2: 2021-04-23 16:14:46.664588+00:00
* adjusted time, dest_time + offset: 2021-04-23 16:14:46.664588+00:00
correction to client: 0.0478968620300293 s

-
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the previous answers are a little confusing about dealy or offset(the half of delay) computing. I'd like to point out this.

In original, ntplib.py source, dest_timestamp(receiving time), orig_timestamp(sending time) are local(client) time. tx_timestamp(sending time from server) and recv_timestamp(receiving time by server) are server time. so the first term in the following code means the packet sending & receiving difference and the second term means prcoessing time in server.

Anyway, adjusted time could be computed like
adjusted_time = response.tx_time + response.delay*0.5

```
@property
def delay(self):
    """round-trip delay"""
    return ((self.dest_timestamp - self.orig_timestamp) -
            (self.tx_timestamp - self.recv_timestamp))
```